# How to define only one unique code to each user by user's ip

Tags: php, mysql, variables, cookies

I want to give to a user his own unique code so that every time he enters my site with his ip (dekstop, mobile and etc) he will receive the same code.

I'v tried using cookies but it's so frustrating and unprofessional that every time I restart my computer/use a different browser/use a different device/use incognito mode it generates me a new code.

I'm kinda new with mysqli, I already tried to replace the "$cookie" lines with mysqli query but then the page didn't load at all..

This is my code, thanks alot!
P.S This code works. When I talked about the page that won't load I was talking about the mysqli option that i'v tried and didn't work.

```
<?php
header("Refresh: 360;");
?>
<?
include "config.php";
if(isset($_COOKIE['my_code'])){
    $code = $_COOKIE['my_code'];
}else{
    $code = rand(1,9).date('Y').date('m').date('d').date('h').date('i').date('s');
    $code = rand_uniqid($code);
    setcookie("my_code",$code, 9999999999);  

    $insert = "insert into cookie_code(user_ip,user_code) values('".getRealIpAddr()."','".$code."');";
    @mysql_query($insert);
```

I want to change the $cookie option with any mysql option that will check if the ip of the user is already in the database, and if it is, so the code from the same row (of the ip) will be given to the user.
If there's no ip that matches the ip of the user, he will get a new generated code.

Edit, FAQ:

- There are no login details, I didn't make any login panel with a
  registration with username&password. I want visitors to enter my site
  and get a unique code that will follow them unless they change the
  ip.
- I know that IP address can't be trusted because it's dynamic, and I
  take into account that there are people from the same household
  that will have the same IP.
- I don't want people to register because i'll lose alot of potential
  users due to their laziness (people don't want to waste time on
  registrations). That's going to be a small project that will generate
  a new code each day (I want to clean the database every 24 hours),
  that's why I dont care using ip.. I just need it to hold for 24
  hours.
- I know i'm using mysql, i'm going to change it to mysqli as soon as
  i'll find a solution for this IP issue

.

Comment: Why don't you just use his username?

Comment: I find it highly amusing that you're worried about the professionalism of having cookies split across browsers, but you're flipping off the camera in your profile pic.

Comment: Never trust an ip unless you are on an intranet where every device has it's own static ip. IPs issued via ISPs are dynamically allocated and most will change after a given time frame, often being recycled to other users.

Comment: are these users logged in? if so you could just add the code to the user table. off topic you should not use mysql_* functions, they are removed from later PHP versions and should be avoided, Also the above is very true, an IP != a user

Comment: What about users coming from the same household? They'd likely have the same IP address, even if they're on different computers.

Comment: Right; and you're using mysql_ - like *that's* professional; maybe back in 90's which should have stayed there. You're probably not using anything safe or at all as a login method.

Comment: [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this. Feel free to upvote that if you agree.

Comment: `date` can take multiple values. `date('Y').date('m').date('d').date('h').date('i').date('s')` can just be `date('Ymdhis')`.

Comment: Hey guys, I'v answered all your questions in the post (managed to edit it. and @Jacobm001 thanks, didn't notice i'm still using that pic lol.

Comment: @BenTyler: That's funny...  The [two images](https://imgur.com/a/mwpBf) don't look like the same person.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Lets stay on topic for now till i'll come up with a solution for my little problem. After that i'll be glad to share with you my puberty albums haha

Comment: So the issue is that the page won't load at all currently? If so check your error logs, you probably are running into a fatal error. Also don't use `@`, that hides error messages from you.

Comment: @chris85 The page works perfect with the cookies option. I meant that when i'm trying to change it to mysql and fetching the ip from the database instead of using cookies it won't load.

Comment: Yea, so you are getting an error. Check the error logs to see what it is. Perhaps you are running PHP 7+ and `mysql_` is no longer available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why bother storing the codes if it's only based on ip address? Just make it on the fly

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$ip .= $today;
$code = sha1($ip);
```

Comment: Hey miknik, thanks for the answer. I do want to store the codes because I didn't decide yet for how long I want to store them. I want to have the option though.